# How can I add this text file to a 2d char array

Tags: java

I am trying to add a text file that looks like this:

```
X X X X X X X X X X 
X S C C C C C C C X
X C C C X C X X C E
X C X X X C X X C X 
X C C C C X X X C X
X X X X C X X X C X
X X X X C X C C C X
X X C X C X X C C X 
X X C C C C C C C X  
X X X X X X C X X X
```

so far I have this:

```
private char[][] maze = new char [100][100];

public void importMaze(String file){
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null){
            int i = 0;
            for(int x = 0; x < line.length(); x++){
                maze[x][i] = line.charAt(x);
            }
            i++;
        }   
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but it is just not working. is there anyone who can help me store this?

Comment: You need to be more descriptive. "It is just not working" is not going to get you much help. If it helps, I think `maze[x][i] = line.charAt(x);` should be `maze[i][x] = line.charAt(x);`.

Comment: *"but it is just not working."*  Try describing a) What you expected to happen b) What actually happened, and for utility c) Why you expected (a) to happen.

Comment: how is `line` ever going to become `null` for your while loop to exit?

Comment: @gpojd what other way is it to describe besides the fact it does not terminate? if it doesnt work it doesnt work, i probably would have listed an error if i got one

Comment: @user3037916, I would have explicitly stated that it didn't terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  Sorry, I haven't tested it.

```
ArrayList<String[]> tmp = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    tmp.add(line.split(" ");
}
String[][] maze = tmp.toArray(new String[tmp.length()][]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.

I would recommend changing from using `line.charAt(x)` to using the splits function.

```
String[] split = line.split(" ");
for (int x = 0; x < split.length; x++){
    maze[i][x] = split[x];

}
```

Also, after you increment i, don't forget to add

```
line = br.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You never updated your line in your while loop... the mistake is here

```
String line = br.readLine(); // <-- This reads one line
while (line != null)
```

to

```
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
```